# Exporting SQL Server table to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, export-to-xml

I'am trying to export SQL Server table to XML file using the following code:

```
Dim ds As New Data.DataSet("MyData")   
Dim QueryStr As String = "Select * from Inventory" 
Dim ConnectionStr as String = "data source=SQLSERVER\ITDB;integrated..."
Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(QueryStr,ConnectionStr)
da.Fill(ds)
da.Dispose()
ds.WriteXml("c:\output.xml")
```

The output format of the XML file is like :

```
<MyData>
<Table>
  <IPAddress>192.168.0.193</IPAddress>
  <UserName>Admin</UserName>
  <Location>Store</Location>
</Table>
</MyData>
```

I want to change the XML file format to be like:

```
<MyData>
<Table IPAddress="192.168.0.193" UsersName="1001" Location="Store" />
</MyData>
```

I need to know what is the name of this format. This format is valid as `XMLDataSource` within `ASPxGriveView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Datacolumn` `ColumnMapping` property to `MappingType.Attribute` for each column you want to be exported as an XML attribute.

```
dataTable = dataSet.Tables["SomeTable"];

foreach (DataColumn dc in dataTable.Columns)
{
    dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
}
```